# php - list folders that contain a specific file

Tags: php, directory

A php script should list all available "modules". A module is a subdirectory that contains at least an `info.php` file.

Now I want a list of all subdirectories that contain the "info.php" file (i.e. a list of all modules) and came up with this code:

```
    $modules = array();

    if ( $handle = opendir( MODULE_DIR ) ) {
        while ( false !== ( $entry = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
            if ( $entry === '.' || $entry === '..' ) { continue; }

            $info_file = MODULE_DIR . $entry . '/info.php';
            if ( ! is_file( $info_file ) ) { continue; }

            $modules[] = $entry;
        }
        closedir( $handle );
    }
```

Question: Is there a shorter/nicer way to get the list, preferably without the loop?

Comment: So far I can see this is standard code. Why do you need a shorter way? The loop is neccessary to iterate through your directories.

Comment: You can skip the test for `.` and `..` It is not necessary.

Comment: hek2mgl: If I skip the test for '..' wouldn't I also check for this file: `/path/to/modules/../info.php`? When the file exists then I include the module-dir '..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice and clean solution can be achieved using the function [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
foreach(glob('src/*/info.php') as $path) {
    echo basename(dirname($path)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: Short and easy to understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the RecursiveDirectoryIterator

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

In your case the code would look like this:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));

foreach($it as $key => $item) {
    if(basename($key) === 'info.php') {
        echo dirname($key) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, why not. You have a well tested PHP class. But that way isn't shorter.

Comment: @Tipo Take a look at the example. Which is more clear to you? It's all about code expressiveness

Comment: Ok, I have to admit. This is much better. Thank you.

Comment: I never used the RecursiveDirectoryIterator before but it looks very interesing. However, I don't want to loop recursivly through subfolders (only direct sub-folders of the module directory)